# Do .net source encryption programs really work?

Tags: c#

Do .net source encryption programs really works?

.Net IL codes can easily be decompiled. There are some encryption software that claim they can hide source from hackers .

Is it true ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can *try*, but any truly determined hacker will be able to hack your code, whatever the encryption/obfuscation.

Since your program needs to be "decrypted" in order to run, the in-memory image could be enough.

If it is simply obfuscation, a bit of hard work can get around that (figuring out functions, giving meaningful names etc).

Comment: I know that every hacker can find and crack software , but I really fear of creating new application like mine , but with his information .
Does obfuscation help me ?

Comment: @pedram - No it doesn't. It just makes you _think_ you are secure.

Comment: So there is no secure in .Net , what about C++?

Comment: @pedram - this is true for any language. If it can run, a hacker will be able to hack it. Get used to the idea.

Comment: @Oded: isn't it a bit excessive to state that obfuscation doesn't help? Nothing will prevent someone to get to the code eventually, but obfuscation can make that painful and time consuming, and fend off the unmotivated.

Comment: @Mathias - I never said it didn't help. I am just saying that it is not effective against someone determined. I know I have de-obfuscated code in the past, and yes, it takes time and effort, but it is hardly something impossible to beat.

Comment: @Mathias - The unmotivated will probably not use the code for anything anyway, you know because they are unmotivated in all. :)

Comment: there's a saying like this:  "for a hacker user, anything works.  For a determined and skilled breaker,  nothing works."

Comment: Obfuscation can raise the bar a bit. But in the end, is all a matter of effort vs. reward: if the price is worth it, then the program *will* be reverse engineered. All one can do is stay ahead of the curve by adding new features, offering exquisite customer support etc etc

Answer (score 5):

The IL can never be encrypted/hidden because the CLR has to have access to it.  The best you can ever do is obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

i used [SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/smartassembly/index.htm) in many projects and it's really good.
here you can read about its [CodeProtection features](http://www.red-gate.com/products/smartassembly/code_protection.htm)

**EDIT!**

true, thats a bad answer from me. i tried SmartAssembly and others like dotfusocator, Salamander,Skater .NET Obfuscator. 
and i never found a good way of reversing applications i protected with SmartAssembly with dynamic proxy etc.

Its my way of saying i like the result från SA more than the others.

But ofcourse if there is a good enough hacker, there is no protection.

*AND I DONT HAVE ANYTHING TODO WITH SA OR REDGATE SOFTWARE*

Comment: "really good" sounds like advertising. What's so good about it?